# browser differences with Transform

Tags: javascript, css, cross-browser, css-transitions

So, I'm just gonna show you my code, maybe something will jump out at you.  I'm playing with some CSS3 and Transform (in the form of a cube)

This is my test site - http://warm-cove-2672.herokuapp.com/

That looks good, and works great inside of Chrome...

Firefox it doesn't keep its shape when you rotate the cube (and it's smaller?)...

IE it doesn't work at all...

**css**

```
#camera {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-perspective: 800;
  -webkit-perspective-origin: 50% 200px;
  -moz-perspective: 800;
  -moz-perspective-origin: 50% 200px;
  -ms-perspective: 800;
  -ms-perspective-origin: 50% 200px;
  -o-perspective: 800;
  -o-perspective-origin: 50% 200px;

  #cube {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 2s linear;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 2s linear;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -ms-transition: -ms-transform 2s linear;
    -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -o-transition: -o-transform 2s linear;
    -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;

    .face {
      position: absolute;
      height: 400px;
      width: 400px;
      padding: 5px;
      border: 20px solid #333;
      text-align: center;
      -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
      -moz-box-sizing:    border-box;
      -ms-box-sizing:     border-box;
      -o-box-sizing:      border-box;
      box-sizing:         border-box;
      font-size: 400px;
      line-height: .9;
    }

    .a { 
      background-color: rgba(255,255,255, 1.0);
      -webkit-transform: translateZ(200px);
      -moz-transform: translateZ(200px);
      -ms-transform: translateZ(200px);
      -o-transform: translateZ(200px);
    }

    .b { 
      background-color: rgba(255,255,255, 1.0);
      -webkit-transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(200px);
      -moz-transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(200px);
      -ms-transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(200px);
      -o-transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(200px);
    }

    .c { 
      background-color: rgba(255,255,255, 1.0);
      -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(200px);
      -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(200px);
      -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(200px);
      -o-transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(200px);
    }

    .d { 
      background-color: rgba(255,255,255, 1.0);
      -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(200px);
      -moz-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(200px);
      -ms-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(200px);
      -o-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(200px);
    }
  }
}
```

**js**

```
$('#cube').css({
  "webkitTransform" : "rotateX("+xAngle+"deg) rotateY("+yAngle+"deg)",
  "mozTransform" : "rotateX("+xAngle+"deg) rotateY("+yAngle+"deg)",
  "msTransform" : "rotateX("+xAngle+"deg) rotateY("+yAngle+"deg)",
  "OTransform" : "rotateX("+xAngle+"deg) rotateY("+yAngle+"deg)",
  "transform" : "rotateX("+xAngle+"deg) rotateY("+yAngle+"deg)"
});
```

Those rotate variables are either +90 or -90 depending on what's clicked.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox isn't liking the perspective property without the 'px'.

Try changing it to:

```
-moz-perspective: 800px;
```

For IE10 - it doesn't support `preserve-3d`.  If you want this to work for IE10 as well you will need to apply transforms to each side.

Stu Nicholls has a demo of this on CSS play: [CSS play - 3D Animated Cube for Internet Explorer IE10](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/cssplay-3d-cube-animation-for-ie10.html)

Comment: nailed FF.  thanks!  any idea on how i should trouble shoot IE?  it's completely foreign to me...

Comment: @Mallanaga I 'accidentally' forgot about the IE part ;)  See my update above.  You will have to change your approach to support IE10.